# Are there idempotent matrices independent of their order?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix $I_n, 0_n$  are idempotent independet of its orden.

Are there others matrix that also holds this property? And if there are, do they have some general form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An $n\times n$ matrix is idempotent if and only if it is conjugate ot an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix that has $k$ $1$s and $n-k$ $0$s in the diagonal, $0\leq k\leq n$. In particular, there are exactly $n+1$ conjugacy classes of idempotent $n\times n$ matrices. This holds over any field.

Any such matrix is of course idempotent.

If $P$ is an idempotent matrix, then $P^2=P$. Therefore the minimal polynomial of $P$ divides $x^2-x = x(x-1)$, so it is squarefree and splits over any field. That means the matrix is diagonalizable, and its only eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$, so $P$ is conjugate to a matrix of the described form.

PS A linear transformation that satisfies $P^2=P$ is called a projection. Idempotent matrices correspond to projections.